# Is a field of a temporary object an rvalue?

Tags: c++

This code compiles successfully under Clang 3.8, GCC 6.3 and VS2013 but fails under Clang 4.0:

```
struct Foo {
  int x[2];
  Foo() {
    x[0] = 3; // line A: works fine - we can assign to x[0]
    *&x[0] = 4; // line B: works fine - we can take the address of x[0]
  }
};

int main() {
  Foo().x[0] = 5; // line C: error: expression is not assignable
  *(Foo().x + 0) = 6; // line D: works fine
}
```

Which compiler is correct? Is `Foo().x[0]` an rvalue or an lvalue?

Lines A and B work on all the compilers, and `x[0]` is definitely an lvalue there, and lines A and B are surely referencing the same `x` as line C, so it seems like `Foo().x[0]` ought to be an lvalue. But maybe the rvalue-ness of `Foo()` propagates to all its fields when accessed in such a way?

Also consider line D, which works on all the compilers. I thought `bar[n]` was basically just syntactic sugar for `*(bar + n)` (for arrays) so it seems strange for line D to work but line C to fail.

Comment: You should not be trying to modify an anonymous temporary.  Besides, what would be the point of such code if it did run?

Comment: This is just a toy example. My real code is something like `glUniformMatrix4fv(&Matrix::MakeOrthographic(1, 2, 3, 4).values[0]);` if that makes sense.

Comment: And that code was working fine until I updated the Android NDK which uses a new version of Clang and now gives "cannot take the address of an rvalue of type 'float'". So I boiled it down to the simplest expression of the problem that I could think of.

Comment: @JohnZwinck: The temporary's destructor does something interesting, for example. Come on... `int main() { File("filename").data = "abc"; }` Guess what `File`'s destructor does. Your comment in unhelpful at best.

Comment: @conio: Your example is not typical of real C++ code seen "in the wild."  Calling a method like `write()` would be allowed.

Comment: @JohnZwinck: Irrelevant. You didn't question the style but rather the usefulness. If someone wants to write Python in C++ he's allowed to. Strange as it may be, there's no law against that. The assumption that accessing data members has no broad interesting side effects is wrong. Period.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Foo().x[0]` was an lvalue in C++11. In C++11, the result of the built-in subscript operator is always an lvalue, since it involves dereferencing a pointer.

In C++14, the behaviour of the built-in subscript operator was changed:

- If `a` is an lvalue, then `a[i]` is an lvalue.
- Otherwise, `a[i]` is an xvalue.

`Foo()` is a prvalue, so accessing a non-static member yields an xvalue. Since `Foo.x` is an xvalue, `Foo.x[0]` is also an xvalue and cannot be assigned to.

Comment: What do you mean by array operand being an lvalue?  Are you referring to the index in the `[]`?

Comment: @Curious In `a[i]` the array operand is `a` (the subscript operand being `i`). Sorry about that, I'll edit.

Comment: Ah ok thanks for the clarification.  Any idea why https://wandbox.org/permlink/Z6L6Jb1Q9Tya7YRt still goes to the `const&` version of the overload?  I thought that this would be an xvalue and therefore would do to the rvalue overload

Comment: @Curious You are not invoking the built-in `[]` operator, but rather the overloaded `[]` operator of `std::array`, which is not ref-qualified, therefore it will always return an lvalue.

Comment: Strange!  Why would that not be ref qualified??  I assumed it would be and didn't even look in the documentation..

Comment: @Curious That's a good question. Vectors and strings don't have ref-qualified subscript operators either. It might be an oversight or it might be to avoid breaking the rule that `c[i]` is the same as `*(c.begin() + i)`. Worth asking a new question.

Comment: Ok yeah, I will ask a new one in a little bit.  I am indeed curious why this is so.  I feel like it will be possible to update the `begin()` iterator also to return an rvalue iterator

Comment: asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44447302/why-do-array-vector-operator-not-have-rvalue-qualified-overloads

Comment: Could you link me to a page that explains the difference in the built in operator[] semantics in C++14?

Comment: @Curious http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access#Built-in_subscript_operator

Comment: That seems to say that the change was made in C++11, am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: @Curious It is an error. You can edit it since it's a wiki. The authoritative reference is of course [expr.sub] in the standard.

Comment: I would be happy to try and edit it, could you point me to where I can find this information in the standard?

Comment: @Curious Just compare [expr.sub] in the C++11 and C++14 standards

Comment: Just curious, do you follow the standards in detail?  I am just wondering how you knew this fact, even though cppreference had it wrong.

Comment: @Curious I follow Stack Overflow. If you spend enough time here and ignore all the questions about Qt and homework assignments, you become aware of most of the subtle points of C++.

Comment: @Curious it's not an error, it's a retroactive application if CWG1213 as noted at the bottom of that cppreference page